# Explorer freezes when getting system notification in Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer, freeze

I am using Windows 10 (64-bit) build 14393.

I had noticed before that `explorer.exe` would freeze with no apparent reason. It wasn't until I opened up VLC to play some music that I noticed that whenever VLC sent a system notification for the playing song, `explorer.exe` would freeze.

I've had to restart it manually all along. I have tried deleting the `BagMRU` and `Bags` folders in the registry, but nothing seemed to happen.

I have auto-hide enabled for the taskbar, if that makes any difference.

Comment: I'm suffering from the same behavior. I also tried to disable any notifications, but still, explorer is freezing.

Comment: My explorer also freezes when a notification happens, it seems to be caused by older software (audio driver, Java, ...) and it takes a while for itself to unfreeze...

Comment: This happens to me as well.

Comment: If you have Realtek sound, see [this post](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/surface/forum/surfpro4-surfdrivers/fix-for-audio-and-hanging-notifications-problems/529c1a05-f0c0-4fbb-b78a-9b0e99326559?page=1).

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be widespread and still happening in 2019. We have several users experiencing this on Windows Server 2016 RDS host, had several contacts with Microsoft support, but "no one knows what could be the cause".

We temporarily solve this (unfreeze) by restarting Windows Explorer (CTRL+SHIFT+ESC to open Task Manager, find Windows Explorer, Restart it).

There is a known issue of Outlook notifications stuck on the bottom right of Windows, and we are about to test disabling all notifications to see if the problem goes away.

On this thread:

https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/after-windows-10-1511-upgrade-pop-up-notifications/85c66732-288f-46bd-aec9-a658e56f3bd3

A guy solved it like this:

> I've stopped the freezing by disabling app notifications as a
>   workaround ("Show app notifications" set to off). I'll leave this to
>   run for a while and if stable, will try switching notifications back
>   on app by app to see if it's a particular one causing the freezes.